# Get data from a site using Selenium-VBA

Tags: vba, selenium

I want to write code to get data from website by ElementID (using selenium and firefox) in VBA, but it isn't working.

```
Public Sub seleniumtutorial()
Dim bot As New WebDriver
Dim i As Integer
Dim vrange As Range
    Set vrange = Range("B1")
i = 1
Do While Len(vrange.Offset(i, 3).Value) > 0

    bot.Start "firefox", "www.*****" & "-v" & vrange.Offset(i, 3).Value & "-en"
    bot.Get "/"
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:3"))
    vrange.Offset(i, 2).Value = bot.FindElementById("stats-container").FindElementsByClass("text-primary").getText()

    i = i + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: What does isn't working mean?  Was there an error message? On which line? And is the URL login based/internal or can it be shared?

Answer (score -1):

```
"www.*****" & "-v" & vrange.Offset(i, 3).Value & "-en"
```

Put that part into a string and make sure that it's a legit URL.  I'm not super familiar with Selenium, but is "/" in a .Get a special command that Selenium recognizes?